# How can I receive UDP datagrams using IronPython 2.7?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ironpython

I'm trying to establish UDP connection from an Arduino to my laptop, both located on a single network with a router. The application I'm working in has IronPython2.7 embedded into it, so this is a fixed parameter. The router has portforwarding configured properly. From my laptop, I send a message to the Arduino, and the Arduino responds with a series of UDP datagrams (a few per second) that I want to laptop to receive.   When I use a separate stand-alone UDP send/receive program on the laptop everything is working fine: I can send a message to the Arduino and it responds, and my laptop receives the data, so I know my router is passing the packets properly. When I use the IronPython program below, the Arduino again receives the message I'm sending out, but the laptop (the UDP server) always gives an error message at the socket.bind statment when I try to bind the IP number to the port (4050) that the Arduino is sending on. I've tried using ' ' instead of the IP number and that gives a different error.  Any help appreciated. I'm pretty new to python programming and brand new to web programming.

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\hamers\source\repos\IronPythonApplication1\IronPythonApplication1\IronPythonApplication1.py", line 16, in 
File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] no addresses of the specified family associated with host
Press any key to continue . . .

```
import socket
localhost="127.0.0.1"
arduinoip="192.168.50.210"
myip="192.168.50.87"     //laptop ip
localreceiveport=4050    //This is the port the Arduino is sending back to my laptop on 
localsendport=4030    //This is the port I use to send do the Arduino
msgfromserver="Hello"
buffersize=1024
UDPServerSocket=socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET,type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPServerSocket.sendto(msgfromserver,(arduinoip,localsendport))
UDPServerSocket.bind(('myip', 4050))
i=0
if i<100:
    i=i+1
    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(buffersize)
    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]
    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)
print "done"
```

Comment: The string 'myip' is not a valid IP address.  Therefore I suggest you replace your `UDPServerSocket.bind(('myip', 4050))` call with `UDPServerSocket.bind((myip, 4050))`, or better yet, with `UDPServerSocket.bind(('', localreceiveport))`

Comment: Thank you for your help!.  When I use either of your suggestions, I get a different error. socket.error {Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied.     Can you explain why you say that 'myip' is not a valid IP address?  Thanks much!

Comment: ‘myip’ is a four letter string literal, not to be confused with myip which is a variable you declared.

Comment: Thanks..  But when I replace 'myip'  with myip  or  ' ',  I get an error saying that an invalid argument was supplied....